# Recursive Function that divides two integers and returns result and remainder

Tags: function, recursion, f#, division

I am trying to create a recursive function that divides two integers n and m and then displays the result and the remainder of the division.

Basicly I created two separate functions which do exactly what I want:

```
let rec div1 (n: int, m: int): int = 
    if n<m then n else div1(n-m, m)
printfn "Remainder: %i" (div1(5,5))

let rec div2 (n: int, m: int): int = 
    if n<m then 0 else 1+div2(n-m, m)
printfn "Result: %i" (div2(5,5))
```

The thing is, I want to do them both at once, I mean in one function like `let rec div12 (n: int) (m : int): int * int =` , not in two separate.
I am not sure how exactly this would work on F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function may return more than just a number. For example, a function may return a tuple of two numbers:

```
let f x = (x, x+5)
f 5
> (5, 10)
```

Further, you can destructure return value of such a function in a similar way:

```
let (x, y) = f 5
x
> 5
y
> 10
```

Now we can use this to have our div+mod function return two results - remainder and quotient:

```
let rec divMod n m = 
    if n < m 
    then 
      (n, 0)
    else
      let (remainder, quotient) = divMod (n-m) m
      (remainder, quotient + 1)
```

Note how this function simply combines results of your `div1` and `div2` in a tuple, then destructures them after the recursive call.

```
divMod 5 5
> (0, 1)
divMod 5 3
> (2, 1)
divMod 7 3
> (1, 2)
```

---

Also note that I'm using curried parameters `divMod n m` instead of tupled parameters as you do `div1 (n, m)`. Ultimately this is a matter of taste, but as a pro tip, I'd like to point out that curried parameters turn out to be much more useful in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I got it!